# Specflow - Raise Build error when Ambiguous steps found

Tags: nunit, specflow

We are using Specflow3 with NUnit and using CI/CD pipelines to run automation tests.

When someone checks in a code which results in Ambiguous step definition, we were not able to catch it during design time. Is there any way to catch these during the build and fail the build in pipeline?

Comment: Doesn't it already fail the build when running tests?

Comment: Do your tests go through code review? They should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible. The evaluation of the bindings is completely done at runtime and not at compile time.

You can only configure how the missing or pending steps are reported. If it is an error or an inconclusive warning.

The name of the property is `missingOrPendingStepsOutcome` - https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Configuration/Configuration.html#runtime